# Offering more elements to a Priority Queue?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I was wondering why the output for the following is [12, 15, 12]? I know that Priority Queue sorts its elements through heaps, but how come 12 is not put before the 15? Thank you so much! :)

```
Queue<Integer> q;
q= new PriorityQueue<>();
q.offer(15);
q.offer(12);
q.offer(2);
q.poll();
q.offer(q.peek());
q.peek();
System.out.println(q);
```

Comment: The `toString()` method of the queue does not show the elements in order.

Comment: Alright; is there a certain order that the toString() method does use? Also, does System.out.println count as toString() in my case? Thank you :)

Comment: println just calls toString on whatever parameter it gets. You can check the docs to see what toString PriorityQueue uses, it's the one in AbstractCollection, you can review the source for that. But basically this is just a convenience to show what's in the collection. You should not be relying on its order for anything.

Comment: I think you need a better understanding of how a heap structure works. The first element is always the smallest (or largest in a max heap), and then the rest are in a heap structure (which keeps track of ordering differently than just keeping a sorted list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get in the habit of consulting the Javadoc for JDK classes.

`System.out.println(q)`, according to [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-), calls `String.valueOf(q)`, which according to [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-) calls `q.toString()`, which according to [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--) uses the order of elements from `q.iterator()`, which according to [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator--) is not in any particular order.

If you think about how priority-queues are implemented (typically as some sort of heap structure), this makes sense: a heap doesn't keep track of the order of elements, other than to ensure that each node has a lesser value than all of its descendant nodes. To return the elements in a meaningful order would require worst-case O(*n* log *n*) time.